# How do I restart Messages daemon on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, messages

From times to times my Messages on OS X Lion gets crazy and will not load when I try to run it.

When that happens I need to restart OS X and it will work again.

Is there a way to avoid restarting and simply restart Messages daemon/whatever it is? Is there a command to do that on terminal?

---

This is the list of all daemons running on my machine... I cannot see messages there, but I have it running...

```
PID Status  Label
-   0   com.apple.cfpreferences-xpcservice
-   0   com.apple.qtkitserver
-   0   com.apple.cmio.registerassistantservice
1   -   0x7f9e53804140.anonymous.launchd
1661    -   0x7f9e53800f80.anonymous.launchd
1664    -   0x7f9e5380a270.anonymous.distnoted
-   0   com.apple.security.XPCKeychainSandboxCheck
-   0   com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner
-   0   com.apple.automator.xpc.workflowServiceRunner
-   0   com.apple.DataDetectors.DataDetectorsActionService
-   0   com.apple.XType.FontHelper
-   0   com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder
-   0   com.apple.security.pboxd
-   0   com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice
1   -   0x7f9e51c03f00.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51c09630.anonymous.launchd
1274    -   0x7f9e51c0f6f0.anonymous.Safari
1276    -   0x7f9e51c132a0.anonymous.WebProcess
1   -   0x7f9e51c12fa0.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51c12ca0.anonymous.launchd
1449    -   0x7f9e51c08900.anonymous.Activity Monito
-   0   com.apple.imagekit.xpc.sendapplescriptservice
-   0   com.apple.SceneKit.C3DColladaResourcesCoordinator
-   0   com.apple.PDFKit.PDFFileRefsValidator
1   -   0x7f9e51c0f3f0.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51c0caf0.anonymous.launchd
1266    -   0x7f9e51c0c7e0.anonymous.BetterTouchTool
1   -   0x7f9e51e2b190.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51e302d0.anonymous.launchd
1172    -   0x7f9e51e30ef0.anonymous.lsboxd
66  -   0x7f9e51c0d660.anonymous.xpchelper
1   -   0x7f9e51c0d360.anonymous.launchd
35  -   0x7f9e51c0d060.anonymous.mds
-   0   com.apple.AppSandboxSMLoginItemEnabler
-   0   com.apple.photostream-agent.ImageConversionService
1   -   0x7f9e53808ca0.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e53808790.anonymous.launchd
191 -   0x7f9e538044b0.anonymous.PhotoStreamAgen
66  -   0x7f9e5390c4a0.anonymous.xpchelper
1   -   0x7f9e5390c1a0.anonymous.launchd
189 -   0x7f9e5390be90.anonymous.filecoordinatio
1   -   0x7f9e51e2e290.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51e2df90.anonymous.launchd
169 -   0x7f9e51e2dc90.anonymous.imagent
1   -   0x7f9e51e2ae90.anonymous.launchd
167 -   0x7f9e51e2a200.anonymous.com.apple.dock.
1   -   0x7f9e53805060.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e53804d60.anonymous.launchd
148 -   0x7f9e53809990.anonymous.talagent
1   -   0x7f9e53907520.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e53907220.anonymous.launchd
151 -   0x7f9e53905cf0.anonymous.Finder
167 -   com.apple.dock.extra
-   0   com.apple.dock.ecti
1   -   0x7f9e51c09330.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e51c09030.anonymous.launchd
149 -   0x7f9e51c08c10.anonymous.Dock
1   -   0x7f9e53905ff0.anonymous.launchd
131 -   0x7f9e539057d0.anonymous.launchd
139 -   0x7f9e539054d0.anonymous.distnoted
1   -   0x7f9e53800ab0.anonymous.launchd
80  -   0x7f9e538006e0.anonymous.netbiosd
-   0   com.apple.HasTRB
66  -   0x7f9e53901c50.anonymous.xpchelper
1   -   0x7f9e53900d50.anonymous.launchd
38  -   0x7f9e53900a40.anonymous.loginwindow
66  -   0x7f9e51c04f50.anonymous.xpchelper
1   -   0x7f9e51c04c50.anonymous.launchd
53  -   0x7f9e51c04950.anonymous.aosnotifyd
1675    -   0x7f9e51c17760.anonymous.Terminal
1677    -   0x7f9e51c17460.anonymous.login
1678    -   0x7f9e51c17160.anonymous.bash
1683    -   0x7f9e51c18ce0.anonymous.sudo
1684    -   0x7f9e51c02bc0.anonymous.launchctl
1   -   0x7f9e51e30bd0.anonymous.launchd
-   0   com.apple.locum.2D...
-   0   com.apple.locum.63...
-   0   com.apple.xpchelper.59...
1661    -   com.apple.launchd.peruser.89
-   0   com.apple.xpchelper.F8...
131 -   com.apple.launchd.peruser.504
-   0   com.apple.authorizationhost.000...
-   0   com.apple.SecurityAgent.000...
-   0   com.apple.launchd.peruser.212
-   0   com.apple.launchd.peruser.222
-   0   com.apple.xpchelper.DE00000...
-   0   com.apple.launchd.peruser.0
66  -   com.apple.xpchelper.00000000...
-   0   com.apple.msrpc.wkssvc
-   0   com.apple.msrpc.srvsvc
-   0   com.apple.msrpc.netlogon
-   0   com.apple.msrpc.mdssvc
-   0   com.apple.msrpc.lsarpc
-   0   org.x.privileged_startx
-   0   org.postfix.master
21  -   org.ntp.ntpd
-   0   org.cups.cupsd
-   0   com.vix.cron
-   0   com.apple.xserve.serial-ports
-   0   com.apple.xprotectupdater
-   0   com.apple.xpchelper
102 -   com.apple.WindowServer
-   0   com.apple.webdavfs_load_kext
23  -   com.apple.warmd
-   0   com.apple.vsdbutil
-   0   com.apple.var-db-shadow-backup
-   0   com.apple.var-db-dslocal-backup
-   0   com.apple.UserNotificationCenter
11  -   com.apple.UserEventAgent-System
24  -   com.apple.usbmuxd
-   0   com.apple.unmountassistant.sysagent
-   0   com.apple.uninstalld
-   0   com.apple.ucupdate.plist
-   0   com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent.system
-   0   com.apple.taskgated
-   0   com.apple.taskgated-helper
26  -   com.apple.SystemStarter
-   0   com.apple.systempreferences.writeconfig
-   0   com.apple.systempreferences.install
-   0   com.apple.systemkeychain
16  -   com.apple.syslogd
-   0   com.apple.suhelperd
-   0   com.apple.storereceiptinstaller
27  -   com.apple.statd.notify
28  -   com.apple.stackshot
-   0   com.apple.spindump_symbolicator
-   0   com.apple.spindump
-   0   com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.periodic
-   0   com.apple.softwareupdatecheck.initial
-   0   com.apple.smbfs_load_kext
-   0   com.apple.smb.preferences
-   0   com.apple.shutdown_monitor
29  -   com.apple.securityd
-   0   com.apple.SecurityAgent
-   0   com.apple.security.syspolicy
-   0   com.apple.scsid
-   0   com.apple.SCHelper
-   0   com.apple.sandboxd
-   0   com.apple.rpmuxd
-   0   com.apple.rpcbind
-   0   com.apple.RFBEventHelper
31  -   com.apple.revisiond
-   0   com.apple.ReportCrash.Root
-   0   com.apple.RemoteDesktop.PrivilegeProxy
-   0   com.apple.racoon
-   0   com.apple.printtool.daemon
-   0   com.apple.preferences.timezone.auto
-   0   com.apple.preferences.timezone.admintool
18  -   com.apple.powerd
32  -   com.apple.platform.ptmd
-   0   com.apple.pfctl
-   0   com.apple.periodic-weekly
-   0   com.apple.periodic-monthly
-   0   com.apple.periodic-daily
-   0   com.apple.PCIELaneConfigTool
-   0   com.apple.pcastagentconfigd
17  -   com.apple.opendirectoryd
1581    -   com.apple.ocspd
12  -   com.apple.notifyd
-   0   com.apple.nis.ypbind
-   0   com.apple.nfsd
-   0   com.apple.newsyslog
-   0   com.apple.nlcd
80  -   com.apple.netbiosd
-   0   com.apple.netauth.sys.gui
-   0   com.apple.netauth.sys.auth
-   0   com.apple.metadata.mds.spindump
-   0   com.apple.metadata.mds.scan
35  -   com.apple.metadata.mds
-   0   com.apple.mDNSResponderHelper
36  -   com.apple.mDNSResponder
-   0   com.apple.mdmclient.daemon
-   0   com.apple.ManagedClient
38  -   com.apple.loginwindow
125 -   com.apple.logind
-   0   com.apple.locum
-   0   com.apple.lockd
-   0   com.apple.locationd
-   0   com.apple.kuncd
10  -   com.apple.kextd
40  -   com.apple.KernelEventAgent
-   0   com.apple.Kerberos.kpasswdd
-   0   com.apple.Kerberos.kdc
-   0   com.apple.Kerberos.kcm
-   0   com.apple.Kerberos.kadmind
-   0   com.apple.Kerberos.digest-service
-   0   com.apple.kcproxy
-   0   com.apple.installd
-   0   com.apple.IFCStart
42  -   com.apple.hidd
-   0   com.apple.hdiejectd
-   0   com.apple.gssd
15  -   com.apple.fseventsd
-   0   com.apple.FontWorker
-   0   com.apple.fontmover
-   0   com.apple.fontd
-   0   com.apple.findmymacmessenger
-   0   com.apple.findmymacd
189 -   com.apple.FileCoordination
-   0   com.apple.familycontrols
-   0   com.apple.efilogin-helper
-   0   com.apple.eapolcfg_auth
44  -   com.apple.dynamic_pager
-   0   com.apple.dvdplayback.setregion
-   0   com.apple.DumpPanic
-   0   com.apple.DumpGPURestart
-   0   com.apple.instruments.tfp
-   0   com.apple.instruments.server.mig
-   0   com.apple.instruments.dtraced
-   0   com.apple.instruments.activity
-   0   com.apple.dspluginhelperd
46  -   com.apple.dpd
-   0   com.apple.docsetinstalld
19  -   com.apple.distnoted.xpc.daemon
-   0   com.apple.diskmanagementd
13  -   com.apple.diskarbitrationd
-   0   com.apple.DiagnosticReportCleanUp
-   0   com.apple.DeviceManagement.SCEPHelper
107 -   com.apple.cvmsServ
-   0   com.apple.corestorage.corestoragehelperd
-   0   com.apple.corestorage.corestoraged
57  -   com.apple.coreservicesd
-   0   com.apple.coreservices.appleid.passwordcheck
-   0   com.apple.CoreRAID
-   0   com.apple.configureLocalKDC
14  -   com.apple.configd
1278    -   com.apple.cmio.VDCAssistant
-   0   com.apple.cmio.IIDCVideoAssistant
-   0   com.apple.cmio.AVCAssistant
-   0   com.apple.chud.pilotfish
-   0   com.apple.chud.chum
1681    -   com.apple.bsd.launchdadd
-   0   com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
-   0   com.apple.bnepd
49  -   com.apple.blued
1666    -   com.apple.backupd
-   0   com.apple.backupd-wake
-   0   com.apple.backupd-auto
-   0   com.apple.backupd-attach
-   0   com.apple.awacsd
-   0   com.apple.avbdeviced
-   0   com.apple.automountd
50  -   com.apple.autofsd
-   0   com.apple.authorizationhost
-   0   com.apple.auditd
121 -   com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
-   0   com.apple.aslmanager
52  -   com.apple.applepushserviced
208 -   com.apple.appleprofilepolicyd
53  -   com.apple.AOSNotification-FMM
-   0   com.apple.alf
-   0   com.apple.airport.updateprefs
-   0   com.apple.airportd
-   0   com.apple.AirPort.wps
-   0   com.apple.afpfs_checkafp
-   0   com.apple.afpfs_afpLoad
1452    -   com.apple.ActivityMonitor
54  -   com.m-audio.firewire.helper
-   0   com.apple.RemotePairTool
55  -   com.apple.qmaster.qmasterd
-   0   com.apple.aelwriter
-   0   com.apple.launchctl.System
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Messages beta application is no longer available for download from Apple, I can't give the exact commands. Below is a general answer.

`$ sudo launchctl list` might help you to get a list of running daemons. When the first column (PID) is actually not a minus-sign, than it is running. Otherwise the launchd job is loaded and waiting in the background to be started on the corresponding event.

One of the output lines could be:

```
33  -   com.apple.notifyd
```

Next you need to find where its plist file is stored.

```
$ locate com.apple.notifyd
```

Helps here, with output:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.notifyd.plist
...
```

Finally the command to restart is:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.notifyd.plist;sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.notifyd.plist
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show all daemons running. I cannot see messages.

Comment: To try installing Messages over here, is there a download link available for the Messages application for Lion?

Comment: here we go directly from Apple: http://appldnld.apple.com/MessagesBeta/041-4274.20120216.z5km/MessagesBeta.dmg

Comment: One of the new launchctl items that appear after starting iMessage is `0x7f8bf3e42bd0.anonymous.iChat`. Unfortunately anonymous launchctl items can not be restarted with `launchctl`.

Comment: Your iChat item will not be identical. The first dotted part `0x7f8bf3e42bd0` is different every time iMessage is launched. Another note: I could kill the PID of `xyz.anonymous.iChat` but that also killed the iMessage application it selves.